# How to check if a custom solution violates any constraints in ORtools

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming

I'm using the ORTOOLs to solve a CP problem. However, the solution is not really what I expected and there exists a better solution. Therefore, I would like to check if a custom solution is feasible and check which constraint is violated if it's not.
Is there anyway I could do that?
I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only CP-SAT solver has a support for infeasibility explanation.

In Python:

```py
if status == cp_model.INFEASIBLE:
    print(f'{solver.SufficientAssumptionsForInfeasibility()}')
```

see: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/samples/assumptions_sample_sat.py
or
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/samples/assumptions_sample_sat.cc